# Adding element to html page with data from golang

Tags: javascript, html, go, push-notification

I am working on a project which has a notification page and I need to **dynamically update** content of the page without reloading the whole page. The message comes from a package written in go(golang). here is the message :

[image]

How can I add this message to the HTML template?

Comment: I'm using rabbitMQ to send the message

Comment: Never post screenshots of code. Paste the relevant code into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to break down you question, to better understand what you want to achieve

### Facts:

1. You are serving notifications HTML page.
2. Without refreshing the page, you want the content to be updated whenever a **message** arrives.
3. **Message** is being generated by a Golang application.
4. You want to use RabbitMQ to send the Golang generated message to your notifications page.

### One approach:

RabbitMQ works using a [Publisher -> Queue -> Consumer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/img/tutorials/python-one.png) workflow.
Since your message is coming from a Golang application, you could use *Go RabbitMQ client* to send the message to the Queue.
then you could use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) to asynchronously consume messages from the queue and update your notifications page without refreshing it.

### Further reading:

- Check out [this tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-go.html) for using RabbitMQ with Golang.
- Check out [this tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html) for using RabbitMQ with JavaScript.

Hope it helps!